# "Why not do it" vs "why not to do it"

Tags: sentence-construction, to-infinitive

The following sentence came up and started a discussion between me and a friend over the grammar and the use of the word **to**:

> Now that the weather is frightful, why not (**to**) spend the time indoors with friends and family

My friend's argument is that we must use the full infinitive form. To that I argue that we *are* using that form, we should just skip the leading **to**. Which is correct? Should the **to** be there or not?

I believe the following is a minimal, simplified version of the sentence:

> Why not **to** do it

But in this case it makes sense for me to say it both with and without the **to**, although I feel that those two versions have slightly different meanings (I would also put the stress slightly differently in either case):

> Why not *do* it
>
> Why *not* to do it

Whereas it feels incorrect to me (but not to my friend) to use the **to** in the example in the beginning.

Some advice for clearing this out?

Comment: "Why [not] do it" is an imperative question (so it uses the infinite verb, but without the marker 'to').  "Why [not] to do it" is a fragment (not even a sentence) -- marking the verb ('to do') changes it to a noun (like a gerund).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marked infinitive, for example

**to err**

resolves to something like a noun; it plays a nominal role, so that it can be used as a subject or object:

> To err *is* human.

The question-word **why**  wants a verbal complement that resolves to an *action*:

> Why **use** more than one fork, one for salad, one for the main meal, one for dessert?
>
> Why **go** to the beach during a thunderstorm?
>
> Why **take** the crowded highway when you can take a quiet back way with little traffic?
>
> Why **sing** in the shower?

Answer (score 2):

> "Why not do it?"

This example is phrased as a rhetorical question. The word "not" negates the word "why", so you are *asking* for a reason why "it" should not be done.

> "Why not to do it"

In this second example, the word "not" negates the *verb* "*to do*". This is no longer a question, but perhaps how you might begin an explanation of why one should not do something.

> Now that the weather is frightful, why not spend the time indoors with friends and family?

This is also a rhetorical question - a *suggestion* to spend time indoors with friends and family and does not require an answer, unless of course there *is* a reason for the other party to object to the suggestion.